# Is There any way to add outlines to a topographic map shader?

Tags: shader-nodes, freestyle, height-map

I made this shader to take any model and make it into a topographical map but I am having two problems.

I already have a shader but that one requires the mesh to be topographic, and this new one is to make the process faster.

[image: This is the problematic shader setup]

This is the problematic shader setup

1. I can't figure out a way to add outlines to separate what would be different 'layers' of the map without doing them individually with a color ramp. is the any way to say set the value at an increment of the heightmap
2. The edges seem to be blurry for some reason.

This is a control with a proper topographic mesh and what I am aiming for, but the shader doesn't have the outlines[image: this is a control with a proper topographic mesh with freestyle and what I am aiming for, but the shader doesn't have the outlines]